# Is there a way to locate where options are in the interface?

Tags: interface, documentation

I'm new in this and I'm working on the [gingerbread man tutorial](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Your_First_Animation/1.A_static_Gingerbread_Man). My problem is that sometimes I don't find some buttons and I would like to know if there is a tool for finding them.

Comment: For many functions you can press Space in the viewport, a search window will pop up, and then you can type part of the name and it will show up. It doesn't work for buttons in the Properties tabs though.

Comment: @David maybe better to put your comment as an answer.

Comment: Could you be more specific on which button you miss?

Comment: Are you looking for buttons in the UI or on your keyboard (hotkeys)?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a keyboard shortcut you are looking for, you can try searching for the tool in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>*> User preferences > Input*:

[image]

As for external resources, you can try [the wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual), but beware that some parts are incomplete/out of date.

Another external resource which works well is google, usually searching for something like "blender <*function name*>" will get you results.

However, if all else fails you can always ask here ;)